# Android: User input on image

Tags: android

I am trying to add user input on a selected image. So far I am able to select the image, then the keypad of the emulator comes up but the text is not added on the image. Following is the code. Could anyone please help me figure it out? Thanks!

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private EditText textArea;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id

    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");      
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);     
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);        
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    textArea = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ascii_text);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    textArea.setText("");
    textArea.getText();
} }
```

full_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >  

<ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ascii_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:hint=""
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="10"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:minLines="10"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:typeface="monospace" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do Want to set text onto the image?

Comment: The user input should be on the image

Comment: Actually you havent considered any textview which can be added to the image view. Try the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
private BitmapDrawable writeTextOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text) {

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId)
            .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.create("Helvetica", Typeface.BOLD);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTypeface(tf);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTextSize(convertToPixels(mContext, 11));

    Rect textRect = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textRect);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);

    //If the text is bigger than the canvas , reduce the font size
    if(textRect.width() >= (canvas.getWidth() - 4))     //the padding on either sides is considered as 4, so as to appropriately fit in the text
        paint.setTextSize(convertToPixels(mContext, 7));        //Scaling needs to be used for different dpi's

    //Calculate the positions
    int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - 2;     //-2 is for regulating the x position offset

    //"- ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2)" is the distance from the baseline to the center.
    int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2)) ;  

    canvas.drawText(text, xPos, yPos, paint);

    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
}



public static int convertToPixels(Context context, int nDP)
{
    final float conversionScale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    return (int) ((nDP * conversionScale) + 0.5f) ;

}
```

Suggested by @Arun George

Hope this is what you need